# Unable to figure out what's wrong with this Linked List Cycle approache

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I was doing [this Leet problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle/description/?envType=study-plan&id=data-structure-i) and my solution seems to work on the test cases but when I submit it doesn't pass one case and I can't figure out why.

```
var hasCycle = function(head) {
    let map = {};
    while(head){
        if (map[head]) return true;
        map[head] = head;
        head = head.next;
    }
    return false;
};
```

However, when I use a set instead it works just fine with the same logic

```
var hasCycle = function(head) {
    let set = new Set();
    while(head){
        if (set.has(head)) return true;
        set.add(head);
        head = head.next;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `val` isn't guaranteed to be unique. Consider what happens to your `map` when you encounter a `val` you've already seen (but a different list item).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `head` is of type `ListNode` so its an object of some kind.

When you do `map[head]` it's essentially doing a `toString()` on the head rather than referencing it by instance. The Set will actually store the instance and allow the comparison logic you are expecting.